# Removing the isolated pixels / noise from image in Google Earth Engine JavaScript

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to remove the isolated pixels/noise from the image and connect the rest of the pixels. I thought about using connected pixel count to remove the isolated pixels, but could not get it to work. Could anyone give me some ideas?

Here's my code:

```js
/******************************************
 *************** AREA OF STUDY ************
 ******************************************/
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[92.214, 24.121],
    [92.214, 25.165],
    [91.006, 25.165],
    [91.006, 24.121],
    [91.006, 24.121]], null, false);
    

Map.centerObject(roi);

/*******************************************
 ************* VIS PARAMS ******************
 *******************************************/
 var imageVisParam_Median = {"opacity":1,"bands":["VV"],"min":-20.46595116382209,"max":-4.361765242123628,"gamma":1},
    imageVisParam_Mean = {"opacity":1,"bands":["VV"],"min":-20.371954136597587,"max":-4.05261121731109,"gamma":1};
    
var imageVisParam_before = {"opacity":1,"bands":["VV"],"min":-20.29998503628732,"max":-3.9658741450307433,"gamma":1};

var imageVisParam_after = {"opacity":1,"bands":["VV"],"min":-26.303530738499518,"max":-1.63198508225777,"gamma":1};

/******************************************
 ****** FUNCTIONS FOR VARIOUS MONTHS ******
 ******************************************/

var jun = function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 6, 1);
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 6, 30);
    var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
    return filtered;
};

var jul = function (year) {
    var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 7, 1);
    var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 7, 31);
    var filtered = collection.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate));
    return filtered;
};


var otsu = function(histogram) {
  var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
  var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
  var size = means.length().get([0]);
  var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
  var mean = sum.divide(total);
  
  var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);
  
  // Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
  var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
    var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
    var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
        .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        .divide(aCount);
    var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
    var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
    return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
           bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
  });
  
  print(ui.Chart.array.values(ee.Array(bss), 0, means));
  
  // Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
  return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};

/**********************************************
 ********** FILTERING THE COLLECTION **********
 **********************************************/

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'), ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING')))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .select('VV');

/***************************************
 ************ LIST OF YEARS ************
 ***************************************/
var years1 = ee.List.sequence(2015, 2022); // As Sentinel-1 Was launched in April 4, 2014. Some months only have data from 2015
var years2 = ee.List.sequence(2014,2022);

/**********************************************
 * GETTING THE IMAGECOLLECTION FOR EACH MONTH *
 **********************************************/
var junCollection = years2.map(jun);


/***********************************************
 * COMBINING THEM INTO ONE LIST FOR EACH MONTH *
 ***********************************************/
 
var all_jun = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(junCollection).flatten());

//
//var img_id = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20220623T235601_20220623T235626_043797_053A82_015D').select('VV')
//Map.addLayer(img_id, {min: -20.62787023200686, max: 1.5127307176016471}, 'IMG JUN 23', 0)


/*****************************************************
 * FOR VIEWING THE NO. OF ELMENTS IN EACH COLLECTION *
 *****************************************************/
print('all_jun', all_jun);


/*****************************************
 * CALCULATING THE MEDIAN FOR EACH MONTH *
 *****************************************/
var median_jun = all_jun.median().clip(roi);


/*****************************************
 ********* DISPLAYING THE MEDIAN *********
 *****************************************/
Map.addLayer(median_jun, imageVisParam_Median, 'median_jun', 0);



/*****************************************
 ********* DISPLAYING THE MEAN ***********
 *****************************************/
 var med_jun_histogram_2 = median_jun.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram()
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
  geometry: roi, 
  scale: 10,
  bestEffort: true
});
print('med_jun_Hist', med_jun_histogram_2);

var med_jun_threshold = otsu(med_jun_histogram_2.get('VV_histogram'));
print('threshold', med_jun_threshold);
//Map.addLayer(mean_jun, imageVisParam_Mean, 'mean_jun', 0);
var jun_histogram = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: median_jun,
  region: roi,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13
})
print("jun Histogram", jun_histogram)


var water_median_jun = median_jun.lt(med_jun_threshold).selfMask();
Map.addLayer(water_median_jun, {palette: 'darkblue'}, 'Water', 1)
//var water_mask_median_jun = water_median_jun.updateMask(water_median_jun.eq(1));
```

As well as the link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fb0c68c6088fbac83410db28c6910d17

I am trying to remove isolated dots like in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `focalMode`?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do the ```focalMode?```

I tried with:
```var water2 = water_median_jun.focalMode(100, 'circle', 'meters', 1, null);```

```Map.addLayer(water2, {palette: 'darkblue'}, 'Water2', 1)```

But don't see any changes

Comment: Sometimes it might be tricky to notice the differences in the map panel in GEE, fue to the use of pyramids. Try exporting the data to compare them more rigorously